# Swipe for activities in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to build an app in which I want to go to a new page through swipe-say. I have about 10 different pages and I want to go to these pages by swiping. Can I implement these pages as separate activities? Can I swipe from one activity to another? I strongly like to implement these pages in seperate xml files rather than creating everything in a single xml page. But as far as I have searched, there are no proper tutorials or blogs giving an appropriate example of a program implementing swipe. If possible, provide some working codes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a [FragmentPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) is what you want. 
Examples and code on the linked page.
If you build for earlier versions of Android, the necessary code is included in the [Android Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

Comment: You are welcome :).  
If you find an answer to be satisfying you can (should) accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left of that answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, swipe is not identified as a particular gesture.
You can use a `OnTouchListener` registered on your view, and animate your view if the gesture exeeds a certain threshold. 
You can then launch a new activity, or in a simpler way, use a viewFlipper.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the attached link [View flow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow).

I feel it will fit your needs perfectly. You can even create different xmls and inflate them into different view objects and then use the "view flow" to switch between them.

[image: Demo image 1]     [image: Demo image 2]

The "view flow" is perfect for handling both simple & complicated views. The flow indicator on the top of the screen is optional.

I hope it helps..